# Adding a class to a tab from another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Is it possible to add a class to a specific tab from another page.

My example is, I on the home page, I have a slider with 3 slides. There is a call to action on each slide which needs to link to a tab on another page.

So if I have

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo ('url');?>/features/#anchorname
```

on the home page, is there a way of adding an active class on page load to the specific tab?

This is how the content is showed on the page that it needs to be linked to. 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11bbffb588baa4acc55392ff50592993

Thanks in advance. 
Paddy

Comment: You want to set active class on real active tab/menu item?

Comment: See my answer @paddywinz

Comment: The page in question is: http://www.grofar.com/features-2/

Answer (score 0):

The regex gets anchors on URL.

I see that you're not using jQuery, you can try with this

```
var active_section = '' + document.URL.match(/(?:#).*/) ;
if(document.querySelector("a.tab.active")){
document.querySelector("a.tab.active").classList.remove('active');
}
document.querySelector('[href="'+active_section+'"]').className += ' active';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added this as a script, but it goes to a broken link. The page with the sldier on is: http://www.grofar.com/home-2/

Comment: I am a little closer now and linking to the page. but it isn't adding the active class at all.

Comment: @paddywinz Is it working now? I tried here and seems ok